# How to create a new column that numbers each ID

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am trying to create a new column to an existing df that numerates each individual ID. Also, if possible I would like the count to start from 0 instead of 1.

I have tried:

```py
df['Sequence'] = df.groupby('ID')['ID'].transform('count')
```

But I am getting a different output than expected.

This is an example of what I am trying to do:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should use [groupby.cumcount](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to get the output desired:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame([157,157,157,158,158,159,160,160,160,160], columns=['ID'])
    df['Sequence'] = df.groupby('ID').cumcount()
```

Output:

```
Sequence    ID
157         0
157         1
157         2
158         0
158         1
159         0
160         0
160         1
160         2
160         3
```